# Busqueda "simplificada" de un mismo valor en diferentes campos (en una misma tabla)

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Actualmente para lo que menciono uso algo parecido a esto:

```
SELECT * FROM `tabla1` WHERE `c2` LIKE 'leonidas' OR `c1` LIKE 'leonidas' 
OR `c0` LIKE 'leonidas'
```

Lo que me interesa saber es, si puedo hacer algún tipo de agrupamiento de todos los campos donde voy a buscar para solo tener que poner el **"LIKE 'leonidas'"** Una sola vez.

El resultado que busco es mostrar * los datos de la tabla en donde en almenos 1 de los 3 campos (c0,c1 o c2) se encuentre el valor leonidas.

Ejemplo de los datos que me traería la consulta:

```
 1.  id | name  | c1       | c2         |  c0
 2. 3278|   A   | leonidas |  null      |  gorgo 
 3. 3499|   F   | null     |  leonidas  |  leonidas
 4. 4402|   Y   | gorgo    |  plistarco |  leonidas
```

Comment: añade por favor la estructura de tu tabla, así como datos de muestra para que nos quede mas claro y podamos replicar tu escenario y darte solución

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo con el operador de agrupamiento `CONCAT()` indicando dentro de los paréntesis los nombres de las columnas necesarias; separadas por comas y posterior con un solo `LIKE` indicas la coincidencia que debe encontrar

```
SELECT * FROM tabla
WHERE (CONCAT_WS('-', c2, c1, c0) LIKE 'leonidas');
```

**o bien puedes indicar que la coincidencia esta al final de la cadena**

```
SELECT * FROM tabla
WHERE (CONCAT_WS('-', c2, c1, c0) LIKE '%leonidas');
```

**o bien puedes indicar que la coincidencia esta al inicio de la cadena**

```
SELECT * FROM tabla
WHERE (CONCAT_WS('-', c2, c1, c0) LIKE 'leonidas%');
```

Comment: Ojo porque si esta justo en el medio no se la va a reconocer. Aunque la solucion es valida, no se si es la mejor idea... no por la respuesta, si no porque no se que esta buscando exactamente...

Comment: Lo único que le agregaría a esta solución es un separador entre columnas, para evitar el caso que juntas disparen la ocurrencias erróneas, por ej: `'leon', 'idas'`, por ejemplo: `'leon', '|', 'idas'`

Comment: @PatricioMoracho lo acabo de hacer mediante concat_ws

Comment: sigue teniendo el problema que si la cadena concatenada es juan-leonidas-jose no la va a encontrar...

Comment: @gbianchi,  no la tengo del todo claro con mysql, pero `LIKE '%leonidas%'` no debería funcionar? El otro problema que veo es el de los NULLS.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho deberia.. no se que va a hace rcon los nulls... no lo tengo claro en mysql...